# How do I reshape a list of this form?

Tags: list-manipulation, filtering

I apologize if this is an already answered question, but I haven't been able to find it.

I have a long list that has this form:

```
{{{1},2,1},{{0},1,1},{{5,4},1,2},{{1},2,3}}
```

I need to rearrange this type of list to give me the following:

```
{{1,2,1},{0,1,1},{5,1,2},{4,1,2},{1,2,3}}
```

So the first element of each list is either flattened when it contains only one item, or they are applied to make new lists of size 3 when there is more than one item in the first element.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
{{{1}, 2, 1}, {{0}, 1, 1}, {{5, 4}, 1, 2}, {{1}, 2, 3}};
Flatten[Thread /@ %, 1]
```

---

```
{{1, 2, 1}, {0, 1, 1}, {5, 1, 2}, {4, 1, 2}, {1, 2, 3}}
```

Answer (score 5):

```
Distribute[#,List,List,Sequence]&/@lst

(* {{1,2,1},{0,1,1},{5,1,2},{4,1,2},{1,2,3}} *)
```

Comment: (+1) It's a very nice way to use Distribute. :-)

Answer (score 5):

```
list = {{{1}, 2, 1}, {{0}, 1, 1}, {{5, 4}, 1, 2}, {{1}, 2, 3}};

MapAt[Apply @ Sequence, {All, 1}] @ list
```

{{1, 2, 1}, {0, 1, 1}, {5, 4, 1, 2}, {1, 2, 3}}

```
ReplaceAt[x_ :> Sequence @@ x, {All, 1}] @ list
```

{{1, 2, 1}, {0, 1, 1}, {5, 4, 1, 2}, {1, 2, 3}}

**Revision**

As gwr commented the above doesn't return the requested output

Here is a correct solution:

```
Replace[
 ReplaceAt[list, x_ :> Sequence @@ x, Position[list, {_}, 2]],
 {a_List, b__} :> Splice @ Map[Prepend[{b}, #] &, a], {1}]
```

{{1, 2, 1}, {0, 1, 1}, {5, 1, 2}, {4, 1, 2}, {1, 2, 3}}

Comment: Thanks, gwr, I revised my answer

Answer (score 4):

```
list = {{{1}, 2, 1}, {{0}, 1, 1}, {{5, 4}, 1, 2}, {{1}, 2, 3}};
```

Another way to this is as follows:

```
f1 = Flatten@*List @@ # &;

f2 = Splice@Thread[#[[1]] -> Table[#[[2 ;;]], Length@#[[1]]]] &;

f1 /@ f2 /@ list

(*{{1, 2, 1}, {0, 1, 1}, {5, 4, 1}, {4, 1, 2}, {1, 2, 3}}*)
```

Or using `Thread` and `Splice` `Composition` instead of using `Thread` and `Flatten` at level `1`:

```
Splice@*Thread /@ list

(*{{1, 2, 1}, {0, 1, 1}, {5, 1, 2}, {4, 1, 2}, {1, 2, 3}}*)
```

Or using `Replace` at level `1`:

```
Replace[list, {a_List, b__} :> Splice@*Thread@{a, b}, {1}]

(*{{1, 2, 1}, {0, 1, 1}, {5, 1, 2}, {4, 1, 2}, {1, 2, 3}}*)
```

Answer (score 4):

Make a function to separate two different uses of `Map` so they don't interfere with each other

```
v={{{1},2,1},{{0},1,1},{{5,4},1,2},{{1},2,3}};
f1[v_]:=If[Length[First[v]]==1,v,Map[Flatten[{#,Rest[v]}]&,First[v]]]
Partition[Flatten[Map[f1,v]],3]
```

returns

```
{{1,2,1},{0,1,1},{5,1,2},{4,1,2},{1,2,3}}
```

What was I NOT thinking, that `If` isn't necessary, simplify this

```
f[{h_,t__}]:=Map[{#,t}&,h]
Partition[Flatten[Map[f,v]],3]
```

Or if you prefer more punctuation

```
f[{h_,t__}]:={#,t}&/@h
Partition[f/@v//Flatten,3]
```

Test this brutally before you even think of trusting it

Answer (score 4):

Never forget term-rewriting, e.g., rules and replacement:

```
list = {{{1}, 2, 1}, {{0}, 1, 1}, {{5, 4}, 1, 2}, {{1}, 2, 3}};

rules = {
  {{a_}, b_, c_} -> {a,b,c},
  {{a_, b_},c_, d_} -> Splice[ {{a,c,d},{b,c,d}}] 
};

list /. rules
(* {{1,2,1}, {0,1,1}, {5,1,2}, {4,1,2}, {1,2,3}} *)
```

Comment: This is really helpful for other times I might have similar questions. Thank you!

Comment: @juv95 That’s why I thought it should be added. I often prefer a “solid” solution for a problem, where I do not have to read all the details in super efficient functions, whose workings I can’t remember if I am not using them on a weekly basis at least. I find pattern matching and replacement to be a very general and easy to apply approach—it is also extremely readable, which is an under appreciated feature of code.